# How Do I Copy Body Content to Meta Title?

Tags: css, html-lists, meta, head, page-title

I have an online member directory that we've opened up for Google to crawl. All of the member listings are the organization name as the search result title in search results. I am trying to come up with a way to take the member's name from the listing (perhaps plus a little extra static text) and set that as the Meta Title for each member's unique directory listing page.

The directory listing basically contains the code (using parenthesis so the code displays here):

(div id="aaRflVendorDetailOverview")
(ul)
(li)John Doe, PhD(/li)
(li)123 Some St. San Fransisco, CA(/li)
(/ul)
(/div)

I am able to single out just the line from the listing using:

div#aaRflVendorDetailOverview li:first-child

I have not tried too many things because I am not very knowledgeable about this stuff. I am able to single out the line of text (using CSS) that I would like to copy to the header, but I do not know if CSS is capable of doing what I want to do.

Ideally, I would like to take their name line from the listing, "John Doe, PhD" and make the page title into "ABC Member - John Doe, PhD"

Anyone smarter than me know how to accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using CSS, but it is using jQuery.

This snippet should do the trick:

```
$(function () {
$(document).prop('title', $("#aaRflVendorDetailOverview li:first-child").html());
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much. It worked perfectly!!